# What would happen to a person's body if they entered a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, estimation, tidal-effect, wormholes

One of the premises of the classic sci-fi show Farscape is that a person could travel through black holes, I'm curious as to what exactly would happen to a person body if you were to enter a black hole and how far out the premise of traveling through black holes really is?

Answer (score 2):

Because of enormous tidal differences on our bodies, they would turn into spaghetti and break into pieces.

Comment: this seems more like a comment